# How to dynamically generate TestCafe test script where number of testcases would be equal to number items returned by a service call

Tags: node.js, testing, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

```
import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

let appList;
let username = '';
let password = '';

// Start - service call to get JSON Data in appList variable
var requestNode = require('request');
var options = {
   'method': 'GET',
   'url': 'https://********.com/_layouts/15/cors/testcafeapps.ashx',
    'headers': {
    'Authorization': '*****w=='
    }
};
requestNode(options, function (error, response) {

if (error) throw new Error(error);
appList = JSON.parse(response.body);    
});
// End -service call to get JSON Data in appList variable

fixtureValidate
.httpAuth({
username: username,
password: password
})

// iterate through JSON items and create tests for each JSON dataitems
for (const app in appList) {
    test('SSO test for ' + appList[app], async t => {
        console.log('Checking login for ' + appList[app])
        await t
        .navigateTo(appList[app])
    });
}
```

I have written above code where I am trying to perform some test steps for each of the app returned by service call. I get an error as "Source file do not contain valid 'fixture' and 'test' declaration"

Instead of using service call if I use hardcoded JSON and iterate through JSON items then my code works but my actual requirement is to not use hardcoded JSON data instead get data from a Service call. Kindly let me know how I can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

This error appears when a file doesn't contain any tests and this is your case. `request` is an asynchronous function and you don't wait until it is finished and try to run tests for `appList` but `appList` is empty in that moment. To run tests only after executing `request`, you can [`promisify`](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v8.x/docs/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original) your request and use `await` to wait for the results. But instead of promisifying `request`, I recommend using [`axios`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios) to execute API requests.

```js
//runner.js
function DoRequest() {
  return new Promise(function (resolve) {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve([
        'test1',
        'test2',
      ])
    }, 2000)
  });
}
(async () => {
    global.appList = await DoRequest();
    const createTestCafe = require('testcafe');
    const testcafe = await createTestCafe();
    await testcafe
        .createRunner()
        .src('test.js')
        .browsers('chrome')
        .run();
    await testcafe.close();
})();
```

```js
//test.js
fixture('Getting Started')
    .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example');
for (const app in global.appList) {
  test('SSO test for ' + app, async t => {
    await t
      .typeText('#developer-name', 'John Smith')
      .click('#submit-button');
  });
}
```

Comment: function DoRequest(option) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        requestNode(option, function (error, response) {
            if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {
                appList = JSON.parse(response.body);
                resolve(appList);
            } else {
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    });
}
fixture`f1`
    .before(async t => {       
            appList = await DoRequest(options);
    })

for (const app in appList) {
    test('SSO test for ' + app, async t => {
        //actions
    });
}

Comment: I updated my script and using promise function to make sure appList is not empty. I am reading appList value in .before function but I am still getting same error.

Comment: It occurs because the `before` hooks are executed after the initialization of tests. So when the loop is executed, the `before` hook is not fired. For this purpose, you should manually [create a `testcafe` instance](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402640/reference/testcafe-api/testcafe) and use [the runner API](https://testcafe.io/documentation/402641/reference/testcafe-api/runner). I'll add a working example to my answer.